# Why isn't Visual Studio automatically closing the program when error occurs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I get a run-time error, VS normally points me to the line where error occurred. 
But I cannot edit anything until the program closes. And VS doesn't close it for me.
 Instead I have to manually end it in Task Manager (What I have been doing so far)

Now, there must be a more convenient way of closing to program, and getting back to work, 
without the use of Task Manager to do it.
How?

Comment: The reason it doesn't close is because you can find out what caused the error. You can still access locals, statics, etc. Quite convenient for debugging ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is stop button in Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things that you can do to end the program. One common keyboard shortcut is Shift-F5 (stop debugging).

The other is the Stop Debugging button on the VS debugging toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

There's a stop button (green square) on the debug toolbar. That will halt your program (in 99% of time).

The reason it is not stopped automatically, is to allow inspection of your failed program state. But that kind of speaks for itself.

Edit: (oh, sorry it's blue as Rahul's screencapture points out)

Answer (score 1):

There's a Stop button in the VS toolbar:

[image: Stop button]